# Why does changing the copied version of the linkedlist change the original linkedlist?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list, palindrome

```
def is_palindromic_linked_list(head):

    if head is None or head.next is None:
        return True

    slow = head
    fast = head

    while fast is not None and fast.next is not None:
        fast = fast.next.next
        slow = slow.next

    head_second_half = reverse(slow) #6, 4, 2 => 2, 4, 6
    copy_head_second_half = head_second_half #<------HERE: copied linkedlist
    
    while (head is not None and head_second_half is not None):
        if head.value != head_second_half.value:
            break
        head = head.next
        head_second_half = head_second_half.next

    reverse(copy_head_second_half) #<---HERE: reversed the copied version of the linkedlist to set it back to how it was. 

    if head is None or head_second_half is None:
        return True

    return False

def reverse(head):
    
    prev = None

    while (head is not None):

        next = head.next
        head.next  = prev
        prev = head
        head = next

    return prev
```

how does this make any sense? Does linked list work differently than variables in that changing the copied version changes the original?

Comment: For most cases, assignment does not create a copy.

Comment: The linked list isn't copied, just the reference to the linked list. There is only 1 linked list, but 2 variables that point to it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue starts when *mutable* objects comes in play. You are referencing the same object in your case, which means that each label points to the same object.
There is too much to say on this topics, but I suggest reading something starting from [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+mutable+immutable+objects)

Answer (score 0):

When you directly assign original list to copy list you are making reference to it.

You need to use [copy()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html), depending if your list has other objects, you might have to use deepCopy(), it is all explained in the link.

Usage with your example:

- shallow copy

> A shallow copy constructs a new compound object and then (to the extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in
> the original.

```py
    copy_head_second_half = head_second_half.copy() #<------HERE: copied linkedlist
```

- Deep copy

> A deep copy constructs a new compound object and then, recursively, inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original.

```py
    copy_head_second_half = head_second_half.deepCopy() #<------HERE: copied linkedlist
```

Answer (score 0):

As already commented, the `copy_head_second_half` variable gets a reference to the head node of the reversed linked list. No nodes are copied. But please note that the list is already mutated by `reverse`, so even if you thought that you were copying the list with this assignment, it would happen too late: the mutation of the original list already happened.

You need this `copy_head_second_half` variable, not because you need a *copy* of the whole list, but because you need to keep a reference to that head node while `head_second_half` is going to point to other nodes in the loop that follows. Without this copied reference, you would have lost where that second list started!

True, the original list is mutated by the call of `reverse`, but that is why your code calls `reverse` again: that way the mutation will be reversed, and your list will be back in its original state when the function returns.

This is actually good practice: you don't allocate memory for making a copy of half of the list.